# Labelling the Target Variables

Tags: python, matplotlib, label

I am trying to plot Heart Disease against Gender. Here I am trying to label 0 as absent and 1 as present in the fig. Is there is a way of doing it? I have tried the following code and plotted:

```
ax = sns.countplot(x='target', hue='sex', data=heartt)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: So what is the issue? The plot looks fine?

Comment: Hi @pavel I want to label 0 as absent and 1 as present in my fig. Is there a way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't relabel the axis ticks if I were you, unless you're very sure about how seaborn is going to handle the ordering for all your variables. Safer to do it in the data:

```
heartt['target_label'] = heartt['target'].map({0: 'absent', 1: 'present'})
ax = sns.countplot(x='target_label', hue='sex', data=heartt)
plt.show()
```